# Borland C++ Builder 6 Error Reporting

Tags: c++, casting, runtime-error, borland-c++

My program is compiling just fine, and most of my functions in the program work, but when I complete a specific task in my program I get an error:

```
"Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier".
```

My program is huge and has plenty of SQL queries that this could relate to. It would make this process much quicker if this error could give me a line number. Is this possible in Borland?

Comment: You should step through your program using a debugger following the path that brings you to the crashing task to determine which line is causing a problem.  I don't use Borland Builder for C++ so I'm not sure about your actual question though.

Comment: That makes sense, but I need help with where to find this information at within the program.

Comment: Again, I personally don't know anything about Borland Builder, but if it doesn't support giving you a line number when crashing/experiencing a runtime error during a debug session, then doing a step through will be the only way to locate the error.  First place to start is with the queries within that 'specific task' and see where you may be storing a guid/string.  Good luck!

Comment: This is an SQL error message.  The database has no concept of your code or its line numbers.  So no, it cannot report that info to you.  You are going to have to track down which SQL query you are executing that is failing, and then you can look at the input you are sending to it. In SQLServer, a uniqueidentifier must be given a character string that conforms to the supported GUID format that is [documented on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx).